# libGDX Pixmap and Texture performance

Tags: performance, libgdx, textures, render, pixmap

I have a huge amount of 2d images in my game, with multiple layers. I use `spritebatch()` and `orthographicCamera()`. I have some basic questions about performances :

1. Does using Atlas is the faster way to load images ?
2. What is faster to work with, Pixmap (and convert to texture before draw) or Textures?
3. When i make a multiple layer image, should I use `Texture.draw` (or `Pixmap.draw` for Pixmap), make a final image and then render it ? Or should i render everything in the `spritebatch.begin()` and `spritebatch.end()`?
4. Is there a way to track "dirty sprites" (the part of the screen that changed between two frames) and render only this region to increase performance?
5. Also, how can I see the memory amount taken by the program resources, and how should I manage it? (maybe this question is a little more difficult)

Thank you for your help (any other general advice is welcome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, this reduces the number of times textures need to be swapped while rendering. This is typically much faster than using separate images.
2. Not sure what you mean by this, a Pixmap should only be used for textures which need to change dynamically or generated as a form of caching. Anything dynamic (changing many times per second to once per frame) should be done using shaders if possible.
3. Use sprite batch when possible as it reduces the number of draw calls. Typically, Pixmaps should be used only when absolutely needed or you have multiple layers you want to cache together. Caching implies it doesn't change super frequent (i.e. should only change every couple seconds). Since Pixmap relies on using CPU it is very slow if large parts of it are changed often. You also take the hit of having to update textures after you make changes.
4. No, this has to be done by yourself... This very rarely is worth the effort and usually there are other easier approaches such as reducing draw calls and culling instead... However, this is very application specific and this is something you will need to experiment with to see what works best for your application.
5. Many profiling and monitoring tools exist VisualVM for desktop. Android 4.0+ has really good developer tools to keep track of things and the Android development environment will provide information on when GCs occur, memory usage, etc. Of course profiling itself will reduce performance/behavior of your application. [Runtime.getRuntime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime%28%29) also provides some good memory information about the running JVM.

General Advice:

**There is no silver bullet**, everything is application specific and while I have suggested and answered your questions for the general case, not everything applies to all situations. You will have to experiment with your application to find out what works best for you. Also, don't get stuck worrying too much about performance and design, the goal is to make a software product. If you spend too much time worrying about performance then you will never finish any project you start. My best advice is to take a shot at it and learn from the experience. You will make mistakes, we all do, but experience will always help mitigate that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just want to put different images one on the other to create some finals images that i will render as texture. It seems i have to load all in Pixmap format, create the final images, then convert as a texture, and render. Not sure if its optimal thought.

Comment: You don't have to load them all as Pixmaps, you can render to an offscreen buffer and grab the Texture from their using http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ScreenUtils.html It should be faster if you have many images (like 10+).

Comment: @Jyro117 Sorry for this late question. Are you talking about a [Framebuffer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html)?

Comment: Yes, ScreenUtils is just a way to capture the from the current screen's framebuffer.