# Pixmaps or Textures for dynamicalliy colored graphics in LibGdx?

Tags: libgdx

I was trying to create a dynamic array containing sprites, that created from pixmap textures. I want to give randomly different colors to this array elements also.
None is working.

Then I tried to create a single pixmap. That also shows same behavior.

I created a pixmap in `show()` like this:

```java
pixmap = new Pixmap(128, 128, Format.RGBA8888);
Pixmap.setBlending(Pixmap.Blending.None);
pixmap.setColor(128, 0, 0, 1f);
pixmap.fillCircle(64, 64, 64);
texture = new Texture(pixmap);
pixmap.dispose();
```

in `render()`

```java
sprite = new Sprite(texture);
sprite.setPosition(b.getX()-sprite.getWidth()/2, b.getY()-sprite.getHeight()/2);
sprite.draw(batch);
```

Whenever I give an rgb color code, it gives either some different colors or black as output. Tried hex code also.

What wrong I did here?

Previousely I used pixmaps as overlay and single texture etc. But did not go deep in to it and tried.

Here, I planned to draw filled circles with pixmap, instead of using graphics. Because my game elements are very simple filled circles and more than 10 colors I should implement.

These circle objects will be generated dynamically throughout the game.

Now I am wondering what I planned to do will be effective with pixmaps. No exapmples I found on net.

Is it possible to create dynamic array with different colored objects?

Or using graphics is the better option compared to pixmaps?

It would be very helpful if I get suggestions from experienced persons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r,g,b,a` values should be in range from 0f to 1f. And it's bad to create new sprites in `render()`, since it's called every frame.

I'll try to answer your questions with this small code sample (left comments in the code):

```java
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Pixmap pixmap;
    Texture texture;

    Array<Sprite> sprites = new Array<Sprite>();

    @Override
    public void create() {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

        // you should use only one Pixmap object and one Texture object
        pixmap = new Pixmap(128, 128, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setBlending(Pixmap.Blending.None);
        pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        pixmap.fillCircle(64, 64, 64);
        texture = new Texture(pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();

        // generate sprites with different colors
        // r,g,b,a values should be in range from 0f to 1f
        addCircleSprite(128f / 255f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        addCircleSprite(0.4f, 0.2f, 0.5f, 1f);
        addCircleSprite(0.6f, 0f, 1f, 1f);
        addCircleSprite(0.3f, 0.8f, 1f, 1f);
        addCircleSprite(0.1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    }

    void addCircleSprite(float r, float g, float b, float a) {
        // every sprite references on the same Texture object
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.setColor(r, g, b, a);
        // I just set random positions, but you should handle them differently of course
        sprite.setCenter(
            MathUtils.random(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()),
            MathUtils.random(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
        sprites.add(sprite);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        spriteBatch.begin();
        for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
            sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        }
        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        texture.dispose();
    }
}
```

also read this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217460/libgdx-pixmap-and-texture-performance). I guess you could load your `Texture` object from .png file with white circle:

```java
texture = new Texture("whiteCircle.png");
```

but creating `Pixmap` circle with only 64 pixels in radius (and then creating a `Texture` from it) is ok too, shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!I read the sample code and implemented it  in my way.Now a number of problems are pending.It  is showing proper color now.But not getting a smooth circle.Also I never loaded such a whitecircle image.I cant find out its purpose.It would be helpful if you explain a bit.

Comment: The reason, why a pixmap circle is not smooth is because you use the same color for all pixels in the circle. You can't create smooth edge of the circle with square pixels, but to make it look smooth, you can add some partially transparent pixels at the edge. Trying to do this on your own would be overkill, so that's another reason to load textures from files. Just create a smooth circle with some graphic editor and load it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262697/create-pixmap-circle-with-smooth-border

Comment: Also, you probably need another textures in your game. It's recommended to put all your textures in an atlas, so they are all part of the same texture. It will decrease load time and number of texture bindings. If you create pixmap circles programmatically, like you do now, they will represent a separate texture, which means they will always cause extra texture binding. You should read this: https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/Textures

Comment: So you are suggesting me to use white circle graphic instead of creating pixmap objects?IS\s that the better way?

Comment: Yes, and I'll quote the link I left in my answer: "Pixmap should only be used for textures which need to change dynamically or generated as a form of caching.". I assume, you don't need to change circle textures dynamically (i.e. change actual pixels in a texture, not the color/size/etc. of sprite).

Answer (score 1):

`setColor()` takes `r`, `g`, `b`, `a` parameters to convert it to `rgba8888` format -

```java
public void setColor (float r, float g, float b, float a) {
    color = Color.rgba8888(r, g, b, a);
}
```

So set `r`, `g`, `b` and alpha component as floats in the range [0,1].

use

```java
pixmap.setColor(128f/255, 0, 0, 1f);
```

instead of

```java
pixmap.setColor(128, 0, 0, 1f);
```

If you want to use hex then -

```java
Color color = new Color(0x000000a6) //(Black with 65% alpha).
```